# How to get NodeRef of specific folder in Alfresco share using javascript?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am working on Alfresco project for some time. This is my first time facing Alfresco, so the help will be useful.
I need to get a nodeRef of specific folder from one site using JavaScript.
I have not prepare any code, sorry for that, but I haven't idea so far how to start.

Using **companyhome** won't work for me, because I work in Alfresco Share, and Share does not support objects from Repository side, am I right?

For example, if I have site "Documents", inside site I have folder "Report", how to get to the Report folder using javascript, and how to list children of folder Report?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to tag Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you install [js-console](https://github.com/share-extras/js-console) first, which gives you an interactive javascript console in Share's Admin-Tools. The js-console supports autocomplete (ctl-space) like a IDE and is the best way to learn and implement js in Alfresco.

There is no reason why `companyhome` should not work. Maybe your Alfresco is configured to have a different mount point instead of companyhome?

You could use different js apis to get the reports nodeRef:

1. `childByNamePath` from companyhome

   ```
   var reportsNode = companyhome.childByNamePath('/Sites/documents/documentLibrary/Reports');
   ```
2. `siteService` API

   ```
   var docLib = siteService.getSite("documents").getContainer('documentLibrary')
   if (docLib){
       var reportsNode = docLib.childByNamePath('Reports')
       if (reportsNode){
           logger.log("Reports folder: " + reportsNode.displayPath + '/' + reportsNode.name);
       }
   }
   ```

Once you have the reportsNode you could iterate over the childs and do what you want to do:

```
for each (var node in reportsNode.children){
    logger.log(node.displayPath + '/' + node.name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to solve that using your advice!